# Multiple instances of main method in C

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I've got an issue with an assignment, but I'm not asking for help to do the assignment, just single problem.

My code is like this:

```
#include "linux/kernel.h"
#include "linux/unistd.h"
#include <linux/slab.h>

typedef _msg_t msg_t;

struct msg_t { /* members here */ };

static msg_t *bottom = NULL;
static msg_t *top = NULL;

int function_one (argA, argB) {
/* function is working, no need to show code*/
}

int function_two (argA, argB) {
/* function is working, so no need I guess to show the code*/
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
char *in = "This is a testing message";
char msg[50];
int mlen;
function_one(in, strlen(in)+1);
mlen = function_two(msg, 50);
}
```

Here's the problem: When I do the make command from the directory, I get the error

```
/home/<username hidden by me>/dm510/linux-3.18.2/arch/um/os-linux/main.c:118: 
   multipli definition of 'main'
arch/um/kernel/built-in.o:
   /home/<username hidden again>/dm510/linux-3.18.2/arch/um/kernel/file_i_created.c:60 
   first defined here"
```

What does this error mean? I only defined the main method one time in my own file

Comment: and what is your compilation statement? If this is a single file, what propose does `make` serve?

Comment: Are you compiling another file with teh posted one? Maybe you defined 2 main functions....

Comment: `main` makes sense for application code (hosted C code). I guess you are compiling some Linux kernel module (freestanding C code), for which `main` is meaningless. You should edit your question to explain more whay you are trying to do. And remember, *methods* don't exist in standard C, (only *functions* and *variables*, and type definitions).

Comment: The message says you have (at least) two C files, main.c and file_i_created.c that are included in the build.  Both have main() functions. (In C, the term is "function", not "method".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message says you have (at least) two C files, main.c and file_i_created.c that are included in the build. Both have main() functions. (In C, the term is "function", not "method".) Remove one of those source files, or remove/rename the main() function in one of them.

Comment: If you are getting the same error message, then you are still including those same files in the build, maybe in object form only.  Did you remove the .o file(s) from the link, or do you have something being included from a static library?

Comment: I had created files for testing a simple systemcall, and see the kernel respond. I removed the files needed for that system call, but I kept having same compiling error. The thing that worked for me was to delete all the references in all files (including what system calls that could be made, syscall_64.tbl, Makefile and so on), to those files, and then I could do the make command.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple approaches here:

- Usually there is only one main in a program. If so, decide, which is the actual main and rename the other one
- If both mains are essential, you could try  putting them in seperate namespaces

Really can't tell without seeing the `file_i_created.c` code though. Could be something else as well.